# How to align text in android

Tags: android

I want to align my text at the bottom left in android.

Comment: What's your view xml currently?

Comment: What code do you have and what's the xml you're using looking like atm?

Answer (score 39):

If you want to align the text in your TextView to the bottom left, use `android:gravity="bottom|left"`.  If you want to align the TextView to the bottom left of it's container, use `android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"`.

I suspect that you're mis-communicating your true intentions, here, though.  You want to align some text to the bottom left of what?  The screen?  The text's container?

Please try to be more specific with your question.

Bottom left of the screen:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="bottom|left"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: the bottom left of the screen

Comment: I would not use a frame layout for this purpose. Use a relative layout instead.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend a [Relative layout](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html).

Your view would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text aligned bottom left"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

Must be written inside your TextView